# Model Mapper works on Live Code but is not working during JUNITs

Tags: java, rest, modelmapper

**Background**

I have a simple SpringBoot application in which I am testing an UPDATE to my Domain Object from a  DTO. Naturally - I am using a ModelMapper to convert from DTO->Entity. The  issue  I am running into is that while  the ModelMapper is working perfectly in the live run, its not  working  during JUNITs. I put a breakpoint in the `initBaseModelMapper` in my Configuration file during both JUNIT and LIVE runs and the breakpoint hits successfully. But in JUNITS, during the actual mapping - the `null` values are still being applied to the Domain entity but not during the live run which works perfectly.

**Configuration**

```
@Configuration
public class ModelMapperConfiguration {
    @Bean(name = "myEntityMapper")
    public ModelMapper modelMapper() {
        return initBaseModelMapper();
    }
    
    public static ModelMapper initBaseModelMapper() {
        ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
        modelMapper.getConfiguration().setPropertyCondition(Conditions.isNotNull());
        modelMapper.getConfiguration().setSkipNullEnabled(true); // Tried without this as well
        return modelMapper; // Gets hit during LIVE and JUNITS
    }
}
```

**Main Class Method Under Test**

```
public class MyCaseService {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("myEntityMapper")
    private ModelMapper modelMapper;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public @ResponseBody
    MyCaseEntity updateMyCase(
            @Valid final String myCaseId,
            @Valid MyCaseDTO myCase) throws Exception {

        MyCaseEntity existingEntity = entityRepository.find(myCaseId);
        modelMapper.map(myCase, existingEntity);
        return existingEntity;
    }
```

**JUNIT**

I put a breakpoint the the `ModelConfiguration` and I can see it getting Initialized exactly like when the code is running live. However, for some reason, the ModelMapper is IGNORING the skipping of null fields unlike when its running live

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes= {ModelMapperConfiguration.class})
public class MyCaseServiceTest {
    @InjectMocks
    private MyCaseService testSubject;

    @Spy
    @Qualifier("myEntityMapper")
    private ModelMapper modelMapper;
   
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        // Initialized `testEntityCase` etc with Id etc
    }

    @Test
    public void testUpdate() throws Exception {
        Mockito.when(entityRepository.find(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(testEntityCase);
        
        MyCaseEntity myCase = testSubject.updateMyCase(
                "1", 
                testCaseDTO);
        
        assertEquals(1L, myCase.getId().longValue()); // <- Test Fails with NullPointer. Id becomes null during  JUNIT.
    }
```

Comment: I think you have 2 ModelMappers, the one created by the Application start and the Spy, which will be used in the test. Try setting skipNull on the spy on Setup, or try it without the spy

Comment: @turo You are correct.   Spy is injecting its own. But I'd prefer the JUNIT to mimic application startup ModelConfiguration. Reason being tomorrow if someone messes with the  ModelConfiguration - i want my Unit Test to catch it. If I override it in my  JUNIT -  i think the test will pass but it will miss the point of catching the code error. Why isn't the JUNIT  bootstrapping using the preinitialized ModelMapper in the `ContextConfiguration` that I'm providing in the Test Class? Also without the Spy wont work as ModelMapper wont get Injected into the `MyCaseService testSubject`

Comment: `@Spy` creates a new, uninitialized ModelMapper and this one will subsequently be autowired, that's what spys are for. It seems your configuration doesn't create the Service, therefore there is no autowiring, just the mocks/spys get injected through `@InjectMocks`

Comment: @Turo Thanks for this. It really got me thinking and I have spent the past day trying to find an alternative. I am unable to full bootstrap my app so I'm just injecting the Configurations in my OP. But I DO need the same Spy  to intercept calls else Im being forced to DUPLICATE the ModelMapperConfiguration in my JUNIT which is just bad. If tomorrow if someone changes the Live ModelMapperConfiguration - the JUNITs wont reflect those since I'm duplicating the mapper configuration in my test. Looking for alternatives (ie you are 100% right - the test Service is not Autowired as in the OP)

Comment: @Turo, how do you set skipNull on the spy on Setup. I have a similar issue and it seems like my modelmapper mappings are not properly configured during my test cases. I even have @ContextConfiguration(classes = {ModelMapperConfiguration.class})

Comment: I'd say call `modelMapper.getConfiguration().setSkipNullEnabled(true)` in @Before annotated method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to overcome theses Problems is to autowire the constructur of MyCaseService instesd of the private member

```
public class MyCaseService {

    private ModelMapper modelMapper;

    @Autowired 
    MyCaserService(@Qualifier("myEntityMapper") ModelMapper modelMapper) {
        this.modelMapper = modelMapper;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public @ResponseBody
    MyCaseEntity updateMyCase(
            @Valid final String myCaseId,
            @Valid MyCaseDTO myCase) throws Exception {

        MyCaseEntity existingEntity = entityRepository.find(myCaseId);
        modelMapper.map(myCase, existingEntity);
        return existingEntity;
    }
}
```

In the Test you can use the Spy to create the Service

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes= {ModelMapperConfiguration.class})
public class MyCaseServiceTest {

    @Spy
    @Qualifier("myEntityMapper")
    private ModelMapper modelMapper;

    private MyCaseService testSubject;
   
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        testSubject = new MyCaseService(modelMapper);
        // Initialized `testEntityCase` etc with Id etc
    }
...
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems simple and logical - dont know why  I didnt consider Constructor DI :) Appreciate it!!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: could you share a repo, becuase if I use @spy i always get the bean without configs